# I get $d\phi^*\alpha = 0$ for any $1$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This cannot be correct.

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra, pullback

I'm trying to get a hold on differential forms; I'm not sure about the following calculation.
Let $\alpha$ be a 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\alpha(x,y) = a\ dx + b\ dy
\end{equation}
and let $\phi:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a change of coordinates, with $\phi(u,v)=(x,y)$.

I want to explicitly check that $d\phi^*\alpha = \phi^*d\alpha$. When doing the calculations, I get
\begin{align}
\phi^*\alpha(u,v) &= a(\phi(u,v))[\partial_ux\ du + \partial_vx\ dv]+b(\phi(u,v))[\partial_uy\ du + \partial_vy\ dv] = \\
&=[(a\circ\phi)\partial_ux+(b\circ\phi)\partial_uy]\ du + [(a\circ\phi)\partial_vx+(b\circ\phi)\partial_vy]\ dv = \\
&= [\bar{a}\partial_ux+\bar{b}\partial_uy]\ du + [\bar{a}\partial_vx+\bar{b}\partial_vy]\ dv
\end{align}
where $\bar{a}=a\circ\phi$ and $\bar{b}=b\circ\phi$.
Then, I have
\begin{align}
d\phi^*\alpha &= d([\bar{a}\partial_ux+\bar{b}\partial_uy]\ du + [\bar{a}\partial_vx+\bar{b}\partial_vy]\ dv) = \\
&= d([\bar{a}\partial_ux+\bar{b}\partial_uy]\ du) + d([\bar{a}\partial_vx+\bar{b}\partial_vy]\ dv) =\\
&= d\bar{a}[\partial^2_{uu}x\ du+\partial^2_{uv}x\ dv]\ du 
+d\bar{b}[\partial^2_{uu}y\ du+\partial^2_{uv}y\ dv]\ du\ + \\
&\quad+d\bar{a}[\partial^2_{vu}x\ du+\partial^2_{vv}x\ dv]\ dv 
+d\bar{b}[\partial^2_{vu}y\ du+\partial^2_{vv}y\ dv]\ dv = \\
&= d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{uv}x\ dv\ du 
+d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{uv}y\ dv\ du\ +d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{vu}x\ du\ dv 
+d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{vu}y\ du\ dv = \\
&= -d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{uv}x\ du\ dv 
-d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{uv}y\ du\ dv\ +d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{vu}x\ du\ dv 
+d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{vu}y\ du\ dv = \\
&=0
\end{align}
But I guess it cannot be correct, since a $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a volume form) should not be automatically zero. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: On the third line it looks like you have a 3-form rather than a 2-form. You've got a term that has $d\overline{a}$, $dv$ and $du$ all being wedged together. Do you mean a $\partial_{u,v} \overline{a}$ instead?

Comment: Maybe I applied the definition of exterior derivative incorrectly?

Comment: Write $\phi = (\phi_1, \phi_2)$. What would you say $\phi^*dx$ is?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I'd guess $\phi^*dx = \partial_u\phi_1\ du+\partial_v\phi_1\ dv$?

Comment: Right. So as AHusain mentioned, it seems like your second calculation is where the mistake is being made. What would you say $d(fgdu)$ is?

Comment: Wait...$d(fg\ du) = d(fg)\ du = (df\cdot g + f\cdot dg) du$?

Comment: I would write $d(fg)\wedge du$ etc., but yes. In your computation, it seems you're writing $df\wedge dg\wedge du$ instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get the exact point where I get things wrong...

Comment: The third line of your computation. That's what I was referring to in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah maybe I'm getting it...You are saying that $d(\bar{a}\partial_ux\ du) = (d\bar{a}\cdot\partial_ux+\bar{a}\cdot d(\partial_ux))\ du$, right? I might start to see the error...

Comment: Yes, but I would advise using $\wedge$ as this is the standard notation.

Comment: ...? did my answer help or no. It is frustrating to see no response from you

Comment: @Aplateofmomos I'm sorry, but I suggest you don't take late responses personally - this is after all a hobby site, not a place to put stress on folks-

Comment: Well I just wrote really think you'd find value out of it. It upset me to see no response @-marco trevi. Let me know if something didn't make sense in it still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \begin{align}
> d\phi^*\alpha &= 
>  d([\bar{a}\partial_ux+\bar{b}\partial_uy]\ du) + d([\bar{a}\partial_vx+\bar{b}\partial_vy]\ dv) \\
> &= d\bar{a}[\partial^2_{uu}x\ du+\partial^2_{uv}x\ dv]\ du 
> +d\bar{b}[\partial^2_{uu}y\ du+\partial^2_{uv}y\ dv]\ du\ + \\
> &\quad+d\bar{a}[\partial^2_{vu}x\ du+\partial^2_{vv}x\ dv]\ dv 
> +d\bar{b}[\partial^2_{vu}y\ du+\partial^2_{vv}y\ dv]\ dv = \\
> &= d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{uv}x\ dv\ du 
> +d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{uv}y\ dv\ du\ +d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{vu}x\ du\ dv 
> +d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{vu}y\ du\ dv = \\
> &= -d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{uv}x\ du\ dv 
> -d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{uv}y\ du\ dv\ +d\bar{a}\ \partial^2_{vu}x\ du\ dv 
> +d\bar{b}\ \partial^2_{vu}y\ du\ dv = \\
> &=0
> \end{align}

I believe you totally blundered taking the derivative of product in second equality. Correct way:

> $$ d([\bar{a}\partial_ux+\bar{b}\partial_uy]\ du)=  \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u} ( \tilde{a} \partial_u x + \tilde{b} \partial _u y) du + \frac{\partial}{\partial v} ( \tilde{a} \partial_u x + \tilde{b} \partial _u y)dv \right] \wedge du = \partial_v ( \tilde{a} \partial_u x + \tilde{b} \partial_u y) dv \wedge du$$

You need to keep the wedge inserted because if you switch around the order of the term being wedged you get a negative sign. I.e:

$$ dv \wedge du = - du \wedge dv$$